# array.push not working inside forEach loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

Here is my code:

```
let purchasesInfoArray = []

console.log('buyersInfo', buyersInfo)

buyersInfo.forEach((runner) => {
  console.log('runner', runner)

  let purchaseInfo = allPurchase
  let purchaseFunction = {}

  counter = counter + 1;

  console.log('counter é:', counter)

  delete purchaseInfo.friends
  purchaseInfo.priceCents = runner.price
  purchaseInfo.totalTaxPaid = 600
  purchaseInfo.iuguTaxPaid = 198
  purchaseInfo.kmaisTaxPaid = 402
  purchaseInfo.status = 'paid'
  purchaseInfo.runnerCpf = runner.runnerCpf
  purchaseInfo.modality = runner.modality
  purchaseInfo.sex = runner.sex
  purchaseInfo.age = runner.age
  purchaseInfo.birth = runner.birth
  purchaseInfo.buyerName = runner.buyerName

  console.log('número de corredor é:', (oldCounter + counter))

  purchaseInfo.runnerNumber = (oldCounter + counter)
  purchasesInfoArray.push(purchaseInfo)

  console.log('purchase info:', purchaseInfo)
})

console.log(purchasesInfoArray)
```

Why my `purchasesInfoArray` is just populating with the last value??

My `buyersInfo` are:

```
[{ age: 25,
   birth: '15/07/1994',
   buyerName: 'Romário 2',
   kit: 'Básico',
   modality: 'Caminhada',
   price: 60,
   runnerCpf: '012.499.862-32',
   sex: 'man' },
 { age: 25,
   birth: '14/07/1994',
   buyerName: 'Romário 1',
   kit: 'Básico',
   modality: '5 KM',
   price: 60,
   runnerCpf: '012.499.862-30',
   sex: 'man' }]
```

My `purchasesInfoArray` is returning two objects with the last object from array.

Comment: What is `allPurchase`? Every index in the array is referencing that object. You could clone it for each index something like `let purchaseInfo = { ...allPurchase }` should work

Comment: allPurchase is a big object with many fields, i get it inside loop, then i change the fields that are different

Comment: @eeerrrttt you have to make a *copy* of that object.

Comment: it is on top of my node function.

let allPurchase = snap.after.data() (which is an object with many fields from firebase)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change your code to

```
let purchasesInfoArray = []
console.log('buyersInfo', buyersInfo)
buyersInfo.forEach((runner) => {
    console.log('runner', runner)
    let purchaseInfo = {...allPurchase} // <-- This line
    let purchaseFunction = {}
    counter = counter + 1;
    console.log('counter é:', counter)
    delete purchaseInfo.friends
    purchaseInfo.priceCents = runner.price
    purchaseInfo.totalTaxPaid = 600
    purchaseInfo.iuguTaxPaid = 198
    purchaseInfo.kmaisTaxPaid = 402
    purchaseInfo.status = 'paid'
    purchaseInfo.runnerCpf = runner.runnerCpf
    purchaseInfo.modality = runner.modality
    purchaseInfo.sex = runner.sex
    purchaseInfo.age = runner.age
    purchaseInfo.birth = runner.birth
    purchaseInfo.buyerName = runner.buyerName
    console.log('número de corredor é:', (oldCounter + counter))
    purchaseInfo.runnerNumber = (oldCounter + counter)
    purchasesInfoArray.push(purchaseInfo)
    console.log('purchase info:', purchaseInfo)
})
```

To make sure every purchaseInfo is a new reference, otherwise you are just updating allPurchase with every assignment, thus updating every purchaseInfo as they are all sharing the same memory reference.

If you can't use the spread operator because of your javascript version, you can alternatively use the [assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Object/assign) method

```
let purchaseInfo = Object.assign({}, allPurchase);
```